# can't print from remote desktop on Windows Server 2003 R2

Tags: printing, remote-desktop

We have a c# document designer project. We can print documents with this program for most of the customers.

But we faced a problem for the customers which has Windows Server 2003 R2 OS. 
I connect to customer pc via remote desktop connection,

Once I try to print from program it doesn't give any errors but it doesn't print any page either!
But when I send test page from the printer it sends the document without problem.
We did similar problem for Windows server 2008 r2 ,
and it was about group policy settings and the problem is solved,
I wonder if it is similar to that problem.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Ok it seems the problem is about windows service.

We are connectiong remotely to the customer server1 pc and from there again remotely to the rf server2 pc:

in my case:

customer server1 pc is windows server 2003

server2 pc is windows server 2003 r2;

I have moved the windows service to server1 pc and it printed the document without problem.

So I wonder what is the problem with the server2 pc!